# Programmatically change frame of the UIkeyboard after rotation

Tags: ios, iframe, rotation, uikeyboard

Since i have a complex hierarchy of views i handle the rotation manually with CGAffineTransformMakeRotation.

Everything rotates in harmony, status bars, navigation bar etc. The only problem is, if the keyboard was on screen before rotation, it gets the orientation of the satiates bar but its size is not right.

How can i force it to fill the entire width and get the right height?

I tested with a single test UIview and it looks likes this.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15251533/iPhoneSimulatorScreenshot_20120430_133558.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple approach to get rid of this situation.
If you call resignFirstResponder on the Textfield and afterwards becomefirstresdonder consequently.The keyboard appears in the right position after rotation.It also does not disturb the animation if you have one.