# Keyboard appears in wrong orientation in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uikeyboard

I have one `viewcontroller` in application that supports landscape and portrait orientations.

On a button click, a popup appears where I should enter the name. everything works as it should on portrait mode.

[image]

But if I dismiss the keyboard, rotate the device left or right and then open the popup, keyboard still opens in portrait mode.

[image]

I've `shouldAutorotate` returning true and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` returning `AllButUpsideDown` in `viewcontroller`, so rotation happens automatically.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19826115/3423468) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10409487/3423468) options but none of them work.

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Can you display the code you handle your orientation with, potentially with some screenshots if created using IB ?

Comment: @IamNguele I can, but code is in Xamarin.  I Usually avoid putting Xamarin code in questions where I expect native developers to answer if there's no absolute necessity. Unfortunately, It becomes less likely that they will answer. :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40318488/uialertcontroller-addtextfield-orientation-issue-from-ios10-on-ipad#comment68002435_40318488 - may be this can help - read the comments

Comment: I have a client that has almost half their users (~3k effected) with this issue on iPads after upgrading to iOS 10.1.1 (last week). Apple response so far is: Power cycle the device and try again... ;-( and wait for iOS 10.2... They have a couple of devs working on a hack to reset the keyboard manually but it will not be Store acceptable...

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks for the response, can you link any official sources regarding the issue? if there are any topics on apple forums or anything

Comment: BTW, I'm testing on 10.1.1 and 10.0.1. Get same results on both. don't have older ios versions to test.

Comment: @arsena I personally do not have any public links. I know that their bugreporter issue is marked as a dup and of course the dup is not viewable... They got contacted due to the visibility of their app in the medical market... It is a strange bug as getting it to reproduce in order to debug appears to be hardware/firmware/iOS version & App software dependent... but this is not really a new bug, as it surfaced in ios8(?) and was patched and it regressed(?) two versions later... that is why the client is hacking a patch for it, it can be worked around somehow using private apis.

Comment: @arsena I would recommend using bugreporter and see if you get a response...

Comment: thanks, you helped a lot. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, fixed it, my fault I guess.

It seems Keyboard and UIViewController call `supportedInterfaceOrientations` separately and rotate based on its return value. I had an `if-else` statement in there and was returning `AllButUpsideDown` only in some cases. When keyboard checked whether it was supposed to rotate method returned `Portrait`, and for `viewcontroller` value was `AllButUpsideDown`.

So I changed this:

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
    {
        if (someStatement)
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown;
        }
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
    }
```

To this:

```
    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown;
    }
```

And now only `ShouldAutoRotate` decides whether it rotation should happen or not.

To some up it should look like this:

```
public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
    {
        if (someStatement)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I got exactly the same wrong keyboard orientation in some of my view controllers recently after I dropped support for iOS 8 and bumped up the deployment target to iOS 9. It turns out that one of my former colleagues used a [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32010520/1724059) to solve an old problem when the base SDK was iOS 9 (we're now in 10, and 11 when coding from Xcode 9 beta). That solution (basically override UIAlertController's supportedInterfaceOrientations to only allow portrait) would force present the keyboard in portrait with newer SDK + deployment target even though the app window and the alert itself are in landscape.

Removing that override solved the problem and I don't see any issue with alert over alert.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding below code to your viewcontroller's viewDidAppear method

```
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) forKey:@"orientation"];
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:@(self.interfaceOrientation) forKey:@"orientation"];

    }
```

Comment: unfortunately, didn't help

Answer (score -1):

Create subclass of UIAlertController

```
MyAlertController.h //header file
@interface MyAlertController : UIAlertController

@end

MyAlertController.m
@implementation MyAlertController 

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
  return NO;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
  [super supportedInterfaceOrientations];    
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
@end
```

Comment: You should never try to override methods using an extension. If you want to override, you need a subclass, otherwise the behavior will be undefined.

Comment: I agree with you, I change it to subclass the UIAlertController, Thanks for your comment.